# list: command not found

Tags: 16.04

I used these comments:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake gfortran git pkg-config 
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev software-properties-common wget vim
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then appear this issue:

```
redhwan@redhwan:~$ list
No command 'list' found, did you mean:
 Command 'hist' from package 'loki' (universe)
 Command 'flist' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'gist' from package 'yorick' (universe)
 Command 'last' from package 'util-linux' (main)
 Command 'bist' from package 'bist' (universe)
 Command 'klist' from package 'krb5-user' (universe)
 Command 'klist' from package 'heimdal-clients' (universe)
 Command 'dist' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'lift' from package 'lift' (universe)
list: command not found
```

how to fix this issue?

The system: Linux ubuntu16.04

please help or any suggestions

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect that command to do?

Comment: How to fix what ? I don't see that any of the packages you've installed should contain a command called `list`. What  do you expect `list` to do ?

Comment: this problem, I need to use for example redhwan@redhwan:~$ list pip
 or  redhwan@redhwan:~$ list topic
and so on

Comment: There is no "list" command in plain Linux. You may be confusing with `ls` to list files. `list` could have been defined as an alias to `ls`.

Comment: no, there are ls and list. I am sure 100%.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaah Now I get it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using it the wrong way. The [list](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/) command is part of `pip`

```
pip list
```

shows the installed python modules where you used `pip` to install.

`pip3` uses `pip3 list`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Oh My God!. Mental state, please forgive me, I bother you.

Comment: @REDHWAN I do it for the accepted vote ;-) Glad you got it sorted out.